# Expression vectorial to magnetic field $\vec{H}$ in conductor region

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

I have some difficult to figure out the second expression about the contribution of magnetic field as you see below:

Problem:
A wire conductor, infinite long (Z axis), conduct a current constant equal to $I_0$ [A] to infinite semiplane, with condutivity uniform equal to $\sigma$[S/m]. Those variables $r$, $\phi$ e $\theta$ and the unit vectors $\hat{r}_a$, $\hat{\phi}_a$, $\hat{\theta}_a$ are the spherical system coordinates. The expression of A vectorial to magnetic field $\vec{H}$ in conductor region (A/m), ($-\infty<x<\infty$, $-\infty<y<\infty$ and $z<0$) is:

[image: alternatives]

D is correct.

[image: image problem]

My attempt:

I find the first expression kind easily:

Use expression to relate infinite wire and distance in fuction angle $\theta$ find:

$H = \dfrac{I_0}{2\cdot \pi \cdot r\cdot \sin(\theta)}(-\hat{\phi}_a)$
[image]

But the second expression which show the $\cot(\theta) = \dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ I cannot to find to complete the answer D.

My answer would be

$H = \dfrac{I_0}{2\cdot \pi\cdot r\cdot (\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))}(-\hat{\phi}_a)$

Any tips?

Any tips?